# Putting integers in lists in python

Tags: python, math

I am making an nth term calculator and I want the user to enter any sequence they like.

Say if they put: `12, 16, 20, 24`, it will be stored in a list like `[12, 16, 20, 24]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension method:

```
in_str  = "1, 2, 3, 4"
listed = [int(x) for x in in_str.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the input as a string, you can just do the following: `map(lambda x: int(x), "12, 16, 20, 24".split(","))`

More generally, you would want to do:

```
nums = raw_input()
map(int, nums.split(","))
```

Comment: `lambda x: int(x)` can be written more simply as `int`

Comment: or `input()` when using python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
map(int, raw_input().split(","))
```

Make sure to split only by `","` not by `", "`, because the latter will raise a ValueError for an input like `"12,14,17"`: